# Returning the highest score after using COUNT in SQL

Tags: sql, count, max

I am trying to return ONLY the highest score for EACH of several groups in a SQL table. My code looks like this for now (col_1 and col_2 are strings):

```
SELECT col_1, 
    col_2, 
    COUNT(col_2) as new_column
FROM table
WHERE col_1 = "some_condition"
GROUP BY col_2
ORDER BY count(col_2) DESC;
```

I can change the condition to return the values for all of the col_2 scores per col_1, but what I want is JUST the highest score, because I want a table where I can compare multiple records' highest score at once. I have tried using MAX, but you cannot use MAX to nest a COUNT. I have seen other answers to similar questions, and have tried those solutions, and they do not work because of this.

What can I do to return only the highest score that is returned in the COUNT?

Comment: just limit your results ie include `LIMIT 1;` at the very end

Comment: Group by col2 and then count(col2)??

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT col_1, col_2, COUNT(col_2) as new_column,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col_2 ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM table
      WHERE col_1 = "some_condition"
      GROUP BY col_2
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

If you want this for multiple `col_1` values, then you might need to adjust the `WHERE` clause.  This is from your query.

Comment: What does the "t.*" do?

Comment: @Willy_Golden . . . It selects all the columns from the subquery.  You can list the particular columns you want.  That is really a short-hand because that part of the query is not particularly important for showing the logic.